# dynamic img src with concatenation into vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to display image html with vue.js framework which URL contain one absolute path and another relative path depends on object.

I try 2 things with strange behaviour :

**first**

*declare this :*

```
<img src="../assets/items/public/jeune.png" height="50" width="50" alt="logo"></img>
```

*and render that :*

```
<img src="imgs/jeune--public.png" height="50" width="50" alt="logo">
```

The display result is good it display correctly my image

**second**

```
imgPreUrl: '../assets/'
objPublicSelected.logo = items/public/jeune.png
```

*declare this :*

```
<img :src="imgPreUrl + objPublicSelected.logo" height="50" width="50" alt="logo"></img>
```

*and render that :*

```
<img src="../assets/items/public/jeune.png" height="50" width="50" alt="logo">
```

The display result is bad it display nothing image. But strangely the url is good and the same that first declaration example.

**others presentation**

*the two delcaration :*

[image]

*the two generated html :*

[image]

*the two display :*

[image]

All others questions into StackOverflow dealing with no using of brackets but not this exact case.

*I don't understand why it doesn't not display image and how I can do that*

Comment: `:src` will only be evaluated at runtime. You should require all the images you're going to need at runtime and store them in your `data`. Then you can pick any particular image with a `computed` property.

Comment: data contents are the binaries of the images or url ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not the code but probably where you are pointing the url to, are you sure is the correct path.

you can also use some computed property to change the whole url something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/56zw74cp/3/

```
computed: { image_url: function() { return this.imagePreUrl + this.objectPublicSelected   };},
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you cannot display images with **relative file system path** dynamically generated.

To understand why it's helpful to understand why your first example works:

- when having an image with a static **src** it will get translated. The translation is handled by **webpack** (or any other module loader you are using) and not by vue.js itself.
- webpack decides what happens with that **src**, it may get translated to another path (what happens in your case) or even embedded the entire image in the src attribute

When you are using vue's binding the final src is generated at runtime, webpack is not running anymore so there's no one that takes care of transforming the attribute. You end up with whatever you're passing to that attribute.

You can use a **relative path**, but that path needs to be relative to the **URL** currently accessed. Relative file system path will not work as you're not running on the server's file system, but obeying URL rules.

Any absolute **URL** path will obviously work (as long as the path leads to a valid image resource).

Note: because of the way webpack (or other module loaders) works the final path of an image resource is not easy to figure out. For instance: if you have cache busting strategies the final path is totally different from the one that you have on your server's file system.

Comment: Very good explain. Ok for src static and Webpack but if I want to use data objects to persist binaries of the image into data Objects ? URL system can be rejected ?

Comment: As long as your property returns a valid image resource, it will work. The important part is that the image data needs to be accessible by the browser at runtime. This can be an url, a data object anything that the browser can access.